# Hibernate Embedded/Embeddable not null exception

Tags: hibernate, embedded, embeddable

In the owning class:

```
...
@Embedded
private LatLon location;
...
```

In the referenced class:

```
@Embeddable
public class LatLon implements Serializable {
    private double lat;
    private double lon;
    ...
}
```

When I try to save an instance of the owning class with a null value for `LatLon`:

`org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.*.location`.

What can I do to allow this value to be null in the owning class? I have tried making it `Nullable` and that had no effect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's caused by the fact that you have `double` properties in your embeddable class, so that Hibernate generates not null columns for them. Change their types to `Double`.